# Play2 Scala specs2 - multiple test in a single application WithServer

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, specs2

Following the instructions in this [post](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/issues/32) I've been able to run multiple tests in a single `FakeApplication` instance. This allows to significantly reduce the test execution time and to avoid some issues related to `play-reactivemongo` plugin.

So I changed my test class form this:

```
{
  "SomeController" should {
    "do this" in FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = addConf) {
      ...
    }
    "do that" in FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = addConf) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

to this:

```
def application = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = addConf)
step(play.api.Play.start(application))

"SomeController" should {
  "do this" in {
    ...
  }
  "do that" in {
  ...
  }
}

step(play.api.Play.stop())
```

Now the problem is that I have some tests that uses the `WithServer` constructor to run a test server. Like this:

```
{
  "SomeOtherController" should {
    "do this" in new WithServer(app = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = addConf)) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to run a single Test Server for all test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
def application = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = addConf)
def server = TestServer(port = 3333, application)
step(server.start())

"SomeController" should {
  "do this" in {
    ...
  }
  "do that" in {
    ...
  }
}

step(server.stop())
```

Bye

Comment: any reason why you'd use "def" for application and server, as opposed to "val"?  You should be able to mark your own answer as accepted now, too.